# по Intellij Idea

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

Подскажите, как в IDE изменить выделение цветов под курсором, как показано на скрине, (хочу другой цвет поставить)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен в

```
Settings->IDE Settings->Editor->Color and Fonts->General->Identifier under caret
```

параметр `background`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо биг ))))